# is it possible to install infobar launcher in other android phones?

Tags: launcher

I find the Au KDDI infobar launcher really cool, and i was wondering if is it available to download anywhere and if is it possible to install it on other phones like galaxy nexus or nexus 4?

[image]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=G-DPf6aF_lM